# Debugging the code for palindrome pairs in java

Tags: java, debugging, palindrome

I was solving the problem of palindrome pairs on [leetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-pairs/description/). So [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-pairs/discuss/79195/onk2-java-solution-with-trie-structure) I found a complete solution with explanation for it. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class TrieNode {
    TrieNode[] next;
    int index;
    List<Integer> list;

    TrieNode() {
        next = new TrieNode[26];
        index = -1;
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

public class Trie {
    public List<List<Integer>> palindromePairs(String[] words) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();

        TrieNode root = new TrieNode();

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            addWord(root, words[i], i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            search(words, i, root, res);
        }

        return res;
    }

    private void addWord(TrieNode root, String word, int index) {
        for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int j = word.charAt(i) - 'a';

            if (root.next[j] == null) {
                root.next[j] = new TrieNode();
            }

            if (isPalindrome(word, 0, i)) {
                root.list.add(index);
            }

            root = root.next[j];
        }

        root.list.add(index);
        root.index = index;
    }

    private void search(String[] words, int i, TrieNode root, List<List<Integer>> res) {
        for (int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); j++) {
            if (root.index >= 0 && root.index != i && isPalindrome(words[i], j, words[i].length() - 1)) {
                res.add(Arrays.asList(i, root.index));
            }

            root = root.next[words[i].charAt(j) - 'a'];
            if (root == null) return;
        }

        for (int j : root.list) {
            if (i == j) continue;
            res.add(Arrays.asList(i, j));
        }
    }

    private boolean isPalindrome(String word, int i, int j) {
        while (i < j) {
            if (word.charAt(i++) != word.charAt(j--)) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        String[] s = new String[(int) n];
        for (long i = 0; i < n; i++)
            s[(int) i] = sc.nextLine();
        Trie t = new Trie();
        System.out.println(t.palindromePairs(s));
    }
}
```

But now I'm facing some problems with code. By the explanation of algorithm given, I thought it could give us all palindromes in a set of strings. But for example if we have these strings as input:

```
3
abcdfd
cba
cba
```

Obviously we can make two palindromes by concatenating strings. But the code just finds one palindrome pairs. I just can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: I guess you need the first word to be "b" to be able to form "baaab" (a palindrome) or the second word to be "aaabb" to be able to form "bbaaabb" (a palindrome)

Comment: @AleZalazar you are right. I edited the question and added a new example.

Comment: Where do you find a palindrome? The 3rd should be abc. Then you have two [1,2] and [2,1].

Comment: @Melvin (1,2) and (1,3) both make abcdfdcba

Comment: @Melvin but the code only gives one palindrome

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in the above implementation of the `Trie`, every distinc word can only be stored once. Here the second occurrence of  "cba" overrides the previous one with index 2. So when searching for the word "abcdfd", there is only one "cba" in the trie and hence only one palindrome is detected.
As a simple solution, you can keep a list of indices, instead of a single `index` filed, for each `TrieNode` and change your `addWord` and `search` methods accordingly to handle the case of duplicate words.